# How do I go about my very first session 0?

Tags: dnd-5e, session-zero

My friends and I are new to session 0 and I am looking to make our experiences more meaningful and fun.

Comment: Welcome to our stack! When you have a moment, please take the [tour] and you can also visit our [help] for more info.

Comment: The game that I am playing is D&D Beyond.

Comment: @DeadLegend001 D&D Beyond is an online content and tool platform supporting D&D 5th Edition.

Comment: Duplicates are also okay here! It's not a bad thing, but if there is something missing in the other question (or answers!), please let us know so we can figure out what to do to help you.